optimizing the motion of a spacecraft by Lambert
I have a problem to optimize the motion of a spacecraft. It starts relative to point O, moving in an undisturbed near-Earth circular orbit with a radius of 6871 km. The gravitational parameter of the Earth is equal to 3.9860044∙10^14 m^3/s^2. The problem is to fly in dt = 86400 seconds from a point in phase space r0 = (10 km, 100 km, -5 km)^T, v0 = (1 m/s, -10 m/s, 3 m/s)^T to the origin, that is, to the point rf = 0, vf = 0. The initial mass of the spacecraft is equal to 1000 kg, the specific impulse of the spacecraft propulsion system is 220 seconds (2157.463 m/s), and the thrust is varied in range from 0.362 to 100 N. I am trying to minimize the total characteristic velocity of maneuvers dV and find the optimal control u.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Гравитационный параметр Земли
mu = 3.986004418e14  # м^3/с^2

# Начальная и конечная позиции и скорости
r0 = np.array([10e3, 100e3, -5e3])  # м
v0 = np.array([1, -10, 3])  # м/с
rf = np.array([0, 0, 0])  # м
vf = np.array([0, 0, 0])  # м/с
delta_t = 86400  # с

# Функция для решения задачи Ламберта
def lambert(r0, rf, delta_t, mu):
    # Простейшая реализация задачи Ламберта
    # Здесь будем использовать минимизацию
    def objective(v0):
        r = r0
        v = v0
        dt = delta_t / 1000
        for _ in range(1000):
            r = r + v * dt
            a = -mu * r / np.linalg.norm(r)**3
            v = v + a * dt
        return np.linalg.norm(r - rf)

    res = minimize(objective, v0)
    return res.x

v0_opt = lambert(r0, rf, delta_t, mu)

print(f"Оптимальная начальная скорость: {v0_opt} м/с")

# Уравнения движения
def equations_of_motion(t, y, u, mu):
    r = y[:3]
    v = y[3:]
    a = -mu * r / np.linalg.norm(r)**3
    return np.concatenate([v, a + u])

# Сопряженные уравнения
def adjoint_equations(t, lambda_, y, mu):
    r = y[:3]
    v = y[3:]
    lambda_r = lambda_[:3]
    lambda_v = lambda_[3:]
    a = -mu * r / np.linalg.norm(r)**3
    return np.concatenate([
        -lambda_v,
        lambda_r * (3 * mu * np.dot(r, r) / np.linalg.norm(r)**5 - mu / np.linalg.norm(r)**3)
    ])

# Начальные условия
y0 = np.concatenate([r0, v0_opt])
lambda0 = np.zeros(6)

# Условия максимума Гамильтона
def hamiltonian_conditions(t, y, lambda_, T_max):
    lambda_v = lambda_[3:]
    norm_lambda_v = np.linalg.norm(lambda_v)
    if norm_lambda_v == 0:
        u = np.zeros(3)
    else:
        u = -T_max * lambda_v / norm_lambda_v
    return u

# Интеграция системы уравнений движения и сопряженных уравнений
def solve_optimal_control(y0, lambda0, delta_t, mu, T_max):
    def dynamics(t, y_lambda):
        y = y_lambda[:6]
        lambda_ = y_lambda[6:]
        u = hamiltonian_conditions(t, y, lambda_, T_max)
        dy = equations_of_motion(t, y, u, mu)
        d_lambda = adjoint_equations(t, lambda_, y, mu)
        return np.concatenate([dy, d_lambda])

    sol = solve_ivp(dynamics, [0, delta_t], np.concatenate([y0, lambda0]), t_eval=np.linspace(0, delta_t, 1000))
    return sol

# Параметры управления
T_max = 100  # Н

# Решение задачи оптимального управления
sol = solve_optimal_control(y0, lambda0, delta_t, mu, T_max)

# Извлечение результатов
time = sol.t
r_opt = sol.y[:3, :]
v_opt = sol.y[3:6, :]
lambda_opt = sol.y[6:, :]

print("Решение задачи оптимального управления завершено")

# График траектории
plt.figure()
plt.plot(r_opt[0, :], r_opt[1, :], label='Траектория')
plt.scatter([r0[0], rf[0]], [r0[1], rf[1]], c='r', label='Начальная и конечная точки')
plt.xlabel('x (м)')
plt.ylabel('y (м)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.title('Оптимальная траектория')

# График управляющих воздействий
plt.figure()
u_opt = -T_max * lambda_opt[3:, :] / np.linalg.norm(lambda_opt[3:, :], axis=0)
plt.plot(time, u_opt[0, :], label='u_x')
plt.plot(time, u_opt[1, :], label='u_y')
plt.plot(time, u_opt[2, :], label='u_z')
plt.xlabel('Время (с)')
plt.ylabel('Управляющие воздействия (м/с^2)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.title('Оптимальные управляющие воздействия')

plt.show()

I got results:
"Optimal initial speed: [13670.08107957 -180.01571544 19961.83694494] m/s
Solution of the optimal control problem is completed
:109: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
u_opt = -T_max * lambda_opt[3:, :] / np.linalg.norm(lambda_opt[3:, :], axis=0)"
How to solve this problem? Could you help me with that?

This question is similar to: Problem to optimize the motion of a spacecraft. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
